# Why do weak NSString properties not get released in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I wrote the following sample code to see how ARC works

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *myString;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject *myObj;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myString = _myString;
@synthesize myObj = _myObj;
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"Appearing Obj: !%@!",self.myObj);
    NSLog(@"Appearing String: !%@!",self.myString);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.myObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    self.myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Loading Obj %@",self.myObj);
    NSLog(@"Loading String: !%@!",self.myString);
}
```

However surprisingly I got these results:

```
2012-06-19 15:08:22.516 TESTER[4041:f803] Loading Obj (null)
2012-06-19 15:08:22.517 TESTER[4041:f803] Loading String: !!
2012-06-19 15:08:22.533 TESTER[4041:f803] Appearing Obj: !(null)!
2012-06-19 15:08:22.535 TESTER[4041:f803] Appearing String: !!
```

As you can see, Obj got released properly but my string (which is also a weak property) does not print out null...Why not?

Comment: Is the string you are setting in `myString` by any change a string literal (something like @"Hello world!")?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSString` uses all sorts of internal trickery to reuse objects and avoid unnecessary allocations and copies. It can do this because `NSString` instances are immutable. In this case there is probably a shared instance to represent an empty string which is being returned by `[[NSString alloc] init]`, and this shared instance will be retained somewhere else as a singleton.

Comment: That seems to make sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps somebody can check out the NSString source code to confirm this.

Comment: Makes sense, though I wouldn't think it would be wise to rely on this behavior, which seems to just be a manifestation of some optimization, which is subject to change at some future date.

Comment: One of those optimization are that string literals get exist throughout the lifetime of the application. Also, creating a new string with a reference to a string literal (`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello world"];` or `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello world"];`) will return a reference to the exact same string literal (like I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11108549/608157))

Comment: I guess copy will also yield the same shared instance when you call it on a literal string?

Comment: Yes, copy on an immutably string will just return the same instance with a +1 retain count. But like Robert says, you should not rely on this behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

`[[NSString alloc] init]` always returns **identical** value. You can check it by yourself.

```
NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *string3 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"string1 = %p, string2 = %p, string3 = %p", string1, string2, string3)
```

This code returns three identical addresses. In my case, output was:

```
string1 = 0x3e8dd74c, string2 = 0x3e8dd74c, string3 = 0x3e8dd74c
```

That means `[[NSString alloc] init]` returns **Singleton**. Singletons usually can't be released.

Making strings with other methods (like `initWithFormat:`) makes usual 'non-singleton' objects, which usually **can be released**, with some exceptions.

**Further:**
Looking source code (Assembler):

```
-[NSPlaceholderString init]:
00040ea4        f64b009c        movw    r0, 0xb89c
00040ea8        f2c00016        movt    r0, 0x16
00040eac            4478        add     r0, pc
00040eae            4770        bx      lr
```

it would be something like this (in objectiveC)

```
-(id)init
{
    return SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE;
}
```

It might be `kCFEmptyString`, but I'm not sure.