# __weak NSString *text = self.textField.text has inconsistent behaviour

Tags: objective-c

I think I may made a silly mistake, but I can't figure out why:

I have a method and Block to handle some network API like:

```
-(IBAction)confirm:(id)sender {         
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    __weak NSString *anotherNumber = self.nextPhoneTextField.text;
    [SharedInstance bindNewPhoneNumber:self.nextPhoneTextField.text pinCode:self.verifyCodeTextField.text sucess:^(id result) {

      // update phone number
      SharedInstance.phoneNumber = anotherNumber;

    }]; 
}
```

before the block, I can see `newNumber` has value correctly,

However when the block is invoked, the newNumber is nil, instead of the text. But I was able to print `weakSelf.nextPhoneTextField.text`, which is not changed.

Any explainations is appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

After creating a sample project, I found it's not reproducible. the weak string pointer has valid text. Then I start debugging it, and I found that,

In order to avoid the `new` keyword, I changed the pointer name to `anotherNumber`

In my real project, when calling `__weak NSString *anotherNumber = self.nextPhoneTextField.text;` the `anotherNumber` has a new address, rather than the `self.nextPhoneTextField.text;` address:

```
(lldb) p anotherNumber
(__NSCFString *) $2 = 0x00007f88b3ff2960 @"12345678901"
(lldb) p self.nextPhoneTextField.text
(__NSCFString *) $3 = 0x00007f88b15f8690 @"12345678901"
```

However in the sample project, I have the similar function,

```
- (void)clickBlock:(void (^)(NSString * string))block {
    if (block) {
        block(@"haha");
    }
}

- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    __weak NSString *text = self.textField.text;

    [self clickBlock:^(NSString *string) {
        NSLog(text);
        NSLog(string);
    }];
}
```

it is the same address:

```
(lldb) p text
(NSTaggedPointerString *) $2 = 0xa000000747365744 @"test"
(lldb) p self.textField.text
(NSTaggedPointerString *) $3 = 0xa000000747365744 @"test"
```

and the class type changed also... Looking for answers!!!

**Another update:**

I delete the block, simply create two weak pointers with some strings like "hello" and "12345678901", the formmer one has the same address and marked as `NSTaggedPointerString`, however the latter one has different address and marked as `NSCFString`

It seems to me that once the text reach a specific length, it will have the NSCFString and different address, and after some tests, the bounty is 9. once more than 9 words, it will be `NSCFString`, tested on iOS 9.1 iPhone 6S simulator.

on iOS 8.4 simulator, all the strings with different length result in different mem adress and NSCFString

sample project:https://github.com/liuxuan30/WeakStringPointer

Comment: Why not just `SharedInstance.phoneNumber = self.nextPhoneTextField.text;`?

Comment: no particular reason, just trying. I don't add much logic, so I just read the value before user can change it

Comment: guys, I know other ways, but just curious why the newNumber is nil

Comment: I think maybe it's gone out-of-scope as the reference to it within the block doesn't count?  It shouldn't be `weak` anyway; it should be strong and it should be a copy.

Comment: @trojanfoe need confirmation, not guessing :)

Comment: It's really weird. Try this `__weak UITextField *field = self.nextPhoneTextField` and check its value inside the block. And tell us the output

Comment: the problem is why weakSelf works but not the weak string

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr `field` is valid object in the block. but the string not :(

Comment: Try yo make a new project (single view app), add a UITextField, set some value, and add a button in which action method do the same thing. 
But instead of `bindNewPhoneNumber...` method use     `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
    });`

Comment: @arturdev what's this for... you need a demo project? I think I just need some details why only nsstring not work

Comment: Can you just do that please?

Comment: @arturdev I just tried, use __weak for the string pointer, but now it actually has a valid text! why??

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear :) 
Check your project settings. Or maybe you have a Category that affects it.

Comment: And make sure that your target's `Build Configuration` is set to Debug and not Release

Comment: it's debug, but I am truely confused now. what to look for then? I'm using ARC, and it's just a normal block using AFNetworking...

Comment: I am not sure why only the weak string pointer is nil but not weak self in my code.

Comment: Guys, I debugged more, and find the two project has different memory address for setting the text. See my updates in the question. Looking for answers!

Comment: Is the block being invoked asynchronously in your real project?  If so, your sample project does not reproduce it correctly.

Comment: then why it has different class type in my real project and different address? I think it's not related to block, but the setter op. in my real project, given the weak pointer points to another address, it will be dealloc after the execution.

Comment: The asynchronous aspect is very important in order to reproduce the issue.  Work through the execution of both sync/async blocks in that code to see the difference.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't think so, because before the block, the address is different.

Comment: I tried some different strings, one is "hello" and one is "12345678901" the formmer one has the same mem address, but the latter one has different mem address. uploaded demo project to https://github.com/liuxuan30/WeakStringPointer

Comment: I have tested more, interesting thing is, the text setter has different behaviour on iOS 9 and iOS 8. see the updates.

Comment: @arturdev what I tried is not always true, and I can reproduce it. I doubt Apple has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__weak NSString *anotherNumber = self.nextPhoneTextField.text;`

with this line , NSString is **copied by value** and NOT by **reference**, so after assigning a NSString to another NSString , it creates new copy of it and creates a reference to newly created copy and not the original one, and because the reference is weak , the object will be nil after the current function goes out of context ,

If you try to change the textfield's text it will **only** change the textFields text and not `anotherNumber` object.

```
NSString *test = self.nextPhoneTextField.text;
self.nextPhoneTextField.text = @"Something else";
NSSLog(@"Test object contains %@ , the textField contains %@ ",test,self.nextPhoneTextField.text);
```

Your code does following:

1. Creates a new Copy `NSString` from `self.nextPhoneTextField.text`
2. Asigns a new Copy `NSString` to `anotherNumber`
3. Since `anotherNumber` is `__weak` , it will **not retain** the object (`NSString`), it will hold `__weak` reference to this object and after this function goes out of context and it becomes nil.

To confirm this behavior, you can directly log `anotherNumber` after setting its value and in different context

```
__weak NSString *anotherNumber = self.nextPhoneTextField.text;
NSString *strongAnotherNumber = self.nextPhoneTextField.text;
NSLog(@"Weak number - %@ , strong - %@",anotherNumber,strongAnotherNumber);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Block Weak number - %@ , strong - %@",anotherNumber,strongAnotherNumber);
});
```

please also have a look at [Why do weak NSString properties not get released in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107729/why-do-weak-nsstring-properties-not-get-released-in-ios)

Comment: Using your code snipper, `anotherNumber` is logged correctly, and not `nil`, as you stated in your answer.

Comment: yeah , its still there until the function is still running and context is not released

Comment: You could also write out comments after `NSLog` calls that prints the expected output.

Comment: have a look at NSString trickery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107729/why-do-weak-nsstring-properties-not-get-released-in-ios , this will only happen to NSString , other objects would have been released at the same time, NSString tries to reuse the strings and thats why its not releasing at the same time, but its released after the context

Comment: @ogres, try "123456" on iOS9 with my demo project, you will see they are the same address, as NSTaggedPointerString.

Comment: also, are you saying the op '=' for NSString is not like other classes' op? Any doc?

Comment: yeah , it tries to reduce memory usage by reusing the string literals

Comment: you should always compare string with isEqualToString method

Comment: so you think the inconsistence is not bug? I am surprised because the length on iOS9 matters so much. One is by value and one is by reference.

Comment: I don`t think its a bug, NSString is immutable and created only once, compiler and then the system tries to reuse the same immutable NSString when its possible , you wont be able to do anything with NSString , right ? only to read or create a new NSString , so its safe for them to just reuse NSString when its possible and reduce memory usage

Comment: so you are saying, the op '=' for NSString is a copy method? not like other classes?

Comment: I need some doc for `NSString is copied by value and NOT by reference`, do you have any?

Comment: read the doc about NSString at Apple ,

Quote :" Over distributed-object connections, mutable string objects are passed by-reference and immutable string objects are passed by-copy."

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/