# Weak Property in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, weak-references

I have 2 properties that are weak, declared as follows :

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *weakProperty;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableString *weakMutableProperty;

- (void)testNonMutable
{
    NSString *name = @"ABC";
    self.weakProperty = name;    
    name = nil;

    NSLog(@"Printing weak property %@",self.weakProperty);
}

- (void)testMutable
{
     NSMutableString *name = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"ABC"];
     self.weakMutableProperty = name;
     name = nil;

     NSLog(@"Mutable : Printing weak property %@",self.weakMutableProperty);
}
```

I was expecting the NSLog statement to print nil , but it prints ABC in the first method. However it does in the second method.
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: OP: Pay attention to the "literals and constants" part of that answer...

Comment: i am not able to mark this question as duplicate, so:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107729/why-do-weak-nsstring-properties-not-get-released-in-ios

Comment: Actually, that's a better duplicate, @AndréSlotta, thanks.

Comment: @trojanfoe, would you care to change the dupe target to André Slotta's link?

Comment: @JoshCaswell but your thread has a more complete answer i think... ;)

Comment: @Josh Caswell  Thanks :)

Comment: I agree; it covers this question too.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's true, @AndréSlotta; it's interesting that there's [another long, well-written answer by David Röhnqvist](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1H9sV.png) at your link, but unfortunately he's deleted it.

Comment: Glad I could help, @PreethamBaliga.

Comment: Can't add answer now, so just write comment: `@"ABC"` is constant string it will never be released. In second method you need use `@autoreleasepool` or `[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithSting:]`